# Microsoft Graph API Look for folder in Sharepoint that contains another, specyfic folder

Tags: microsoft-graph, java

I try to get list of all folders that contain specific folder (always with the same name). So for example if my library in Sharepoint would look like this and I would like to look for all folders that have 'SubFolder':

- Folder 1

  - SubFolder

- Folder 2

  - OtherSubFolder
- Folder 3

  - SubFolder

As a result of my query I would like to have 'Folder 1' and 'Folder 3' (Ideally would be also content of subfolder).

So far I've tried to:

List all the folder from root and then one by one check if there is an item subfolder into it:

```
 public List<DriveItem> getList() throws Exception {
        final List<DriveItem> rootList = this.getRootFolders().stream().filter(e->e.folder!=null).toList();
        for(DriveItem folder : rootList ) {
            try
            {
                final DriveItem customerList = _userClient
                    .sites("example.sharepoint.com")
                    .drives("exampleDriverId")
                    .root()
                    .itemWithPath("/" + folder .name + "/subFolder")
                    .buildRequest()
                    .get();
            }catch (GraphServiceException graphServiceException) {
                    if (graphServiceException.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        this.log.error("Error: ", graphServiceException);
                        
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.log.error("Error: ", e);
                    
                }
        }
 }
```

But this is highly inefficient.

I've also tried to use lists:

```
private List<DriveItem> getRootFolders() {
    ListItemCollectionRequest itemsListRequest = _userClient

        .sites("example.sharepoint.com")
        .lists("example-list-id")
        .items()
        .buildRequest()
        .expand("fields")
        .filter("fields/ContentType eq 'Folder'");
    itemsListRequest.addHeader("Prefer","HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly");
    ListItemCollectionPage anotherPage = itemsListRequest.get();
    final List<ListItem> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    while(anotherPage != null) {
        messages.addAll(anotherPage.getCurrentPage());
        final ListItemCollectionRequestBuilder nextPage = anotherPage.getNextPage();
        if (nextPage == null) {
            break;
        } else {
            anotherPage = nextPage.buildRequest().get();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I'm missing index and it's not working. But it still would need to look throughout to find appropriate once.